# Postgresql array_append with Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sql-update, arel

Let's imagine we have a Postgresql table created with simple Rails migration:

```
create_table :messages do |t|
  t.string :tags, array: true, default: [], null: false
end
```

Mission - add new tag to many rows with single query. With raw `SQL` it's quite simple:

```
 UPDATE messages SET tags = array_append(tags, 'new-tag') WHERE NOT ('new-tag' = ANY(tags)) AND id IN (...);
```

Note: please correct me if I should write this query in different way.

But how to do this using `Arel`?

After hours of digging into subject I found such solution but it looks to me too cumbersome and I'm almost sure that it could be done better. Here's my solution:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base; end
t = Message.arel_table

has_tag = -> (tag) {
  quoted = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(tag)
  fun = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ANY', [t[:tags]])

  Arel::Nodes::Equality.new(quoted, fun)
}

append = -> (tag) {
  quoted = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(tag)
  fun = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('array_append', [t[:tags], quoted])
  literal = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(fun.to_sql)

  [t[:tags], literal]
}

in_id = -> (ids) {
  t[:id].in(ids)
}

um = Arel::UpdateManager.new(Message)
um.table(t)
  .where(has_tag['new-tag'].not)
  .where(in_ids[[1,2,3]])
  .set([append['new-tag']])

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(um.to_sql)
```

Is there any way to achieve this in easier way with Arel?

Comment: Maybe: `update_attributes(tags: tags.push('new-tag'))` ? With the trick `tags_will_change!` to tell AR the model is dirty described here: http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/28/rails-4-and-postgres-arrays/

Comment: Exactly - multiple rows at once. Also `push` will duplicate entries in array.